# Как указать условие в Join для group_concat в SQL запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблицы:

```
create table movies (
  id int unsigned auto_increment,
  name varchar(255),
  primary key(id)
);
```

```
insert into movies values (1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2'), (3, 'name3'), (4, 'name4'), (5, 'name5');
```

```
create table movies_genres (
    genre_id int,
    movie_id int
);
```

```
insert into movies_genres values (7,1), (1,1), (10,1), (6,2), (1,2), (3,2), (5,3), (5,4), (2,5), (1,5);
```

Я хочу получить список ID с условием по жанру.

Например, список ID фильмов с жанром 1

```
id, genres
1   7,1,10
2   6,1,3
5   1
```

Обратите внимание, в поле genres я хочу получить и id жанра, который ищу и другие жанры, которые относятся к фильму.

Что я делаю

```
select m.id, group_concat(mg.genre_id) as genres from movies m 
left join movies_genres mg on mg.movie_id = m.id 
and mg.genre_id = 1
group by m.id 
order by m.id desc 
limit 15
```

Что получаю

```
id  genres
5   1
4   (null)
3   (null)
2   1
1   1
```

Вот здесь можно посмотреть: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15aa04/4

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Мне видится, что должен быть стандартный запрос для моей задачи?
Хотелось бы не только решение, но и комментарий? Есть ли легкое решение или здесь видится архитектурная проблема?

Comment: *что я делаю не так?* Самое первое - лепите LEFT JOIN без какого-либо понимания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select m.id, group_concat(mg.genre_id ORDER BY mg.genre_id) as genres 
from movies m 
join movies_genres mg on mg.movie_id = m.id 
group by m.id 
HAVING SUM(mg.genre_id = 1)
order by m.id desc 
limit 15
```

Что изменено в "авторском" запросе:

0. Заменён LEFT JOIN на INNER JOIN.

Тут даже сказать нечего. Кроме настоятельной рекомендации внимательно изучить типы связывания - использование LEFT в запросе свидетельствует об отсутствии понимания и написании именно так "по привычке".

1. Добавлена сортировка в GROUP_CONCAT.

В отсутствии сортировки результат запроса становится недетерминированным (т.е. на одних и тех же данных два выполнения могут вернуть разные данные, потому что сервер без указания порядка имеет право выполнять конкатенацию в произвольном порядке, что в общем нехорошо).

2. Убрано условие `and mg.genre_id = 1` из выражения соединения таблиц.

Нам в итоге требуется получить все жанры, а не только тот, по которому выполняется отбор.

3. Добавлено условие пост-отбора `HAVING SUM(mg.genre_id = 1)`.

Данное условие проверяет все жанры фильма на равенство заданному значению `1`. Для тех фильмов, у которых в списке этот жанр есть, мы получаем сумму `1` (или больше, если таблица связывания допускает дубликаты - а в показанной версии она допускает), а для тех, у кого этого жанра нет, соответственно получаем сумму `0`. В итоге в выходной набор попадут только те записи, у которых в списке заданный жанр присутствует.

Answer (score -1):

Запрос может быть следующим:

```
select 
    m.id, group_concat(mg.genre_id) as genres 
from movies m 
left join movies_genres mg on mg.movie_id = m.id
where m.id in (
    select movie_id from movies_genres mg where mg.genre_id = 1
)
group by m.id 
order by m.id desc 
limit 15;
```

[DB Fiddle here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=6ce44c0cd1fac2a9f0e181e1ba96c1ca&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Запрос содержит логическое противоречие (порождаемое использованием внешнего связывания). Нет, результат он даст верный, но заставит сервер выполнить много ненужной работы, результат которой будет заведомо отброшен на более поздних этапах исполнения. Ну и WHERE IN - это заведомый тормоз.